# Debug console not showing values for Swift + Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2, xcode7

My app uses Swift and a 3rd-party library in Objective-C. When my debugger steps into the Objective-C code, the debug console does not show the values of my Swift string correctly.  Instead, it shows unable to read data.  How can we resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: When I create strings in Swift, they always show up as `(String)` - so perhaps the issue is related to the fact that its `(Swift._NSContiguousString)`? Perhaps you have to convert it to a String? I've seen issues related to this with Parse, are you using Parse?

Comment: @Mike I am using Auth0.  email and username are declared as String.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using xcode 7.3 you can debug swift classes but xcode less than 7.3 you can debug for objective c class. Both swift and objective c support is not there. You can copy paste those objective c variables and you can print objective c variables by "po objectiveC_variable".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might be using objective C bridging header also to use objective c library in Swift. I see both email and password is shown as Swift._NSContiguousString.And that may be the case if the **bridging header** that you made for your library might be giving some problem or not executing properly ,not sure. Because if the bridging was working then Swift._NSContiguousString would have been treated as "NSString" and you could convert it to as "String" simply.This is what I think ,you can jus check on the bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `po {{variable_name}}` on lldb for print runtime value
and also use `e {{variable_name}}` for print and `e {{variable_name}} = {{value}}` for set new value.

***attention:*** when you use po autocomplete work, but when use e autocomplete doesn't work.